# ¿Extraer campos de archivo VEP-annotated VCF?

Tags: python, bash

Quiero extraer el `Hugo gene symbol` del campo `INFO "CSQ"` de un `VCF` anotado con VEP.

Lo he intentado con `grep` pero no he podido. Básicamente lo que quiero es extraer todo lo que esté entre el tercer y cuarto `pipe`.

¿Alguna sugerencia?

Copio el valor de la celda donde está `CSQ` dentro de la colunma `INFO`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 2 cosas, traduce el titulo a español, ya que estas en SO en **español** y segundo en lugar de una imagen creo que si puedes copiar correctamente el valor de la celda es mejor compartirlo en formato texto que en una imagen por si alguien lo necesitara

Answer (score 1):

Como me da flojera transcribir esa cadena, lo hice con datos dummy.

Puedes usar tanto `cut` como `awk`.

```
$ cut -d '|' -f 4 <<< '0|111111|222222|333333|444444|555555'
333333
$ awk -F '|' '{print $4}' <<< '0|111111|222222|333333|444444|555555'
333333
```

Lo que hago en ambos casos es separar por el caracter '|' y tomo el cuarto campo.